# Celltable GWT Sorting

Tags: gwt, celltable, gwt-celltable

i've been searching now for couple of days but i cannot find something that helps me.

I have a few columns and sorthandlers, so the sorting itself is no problem.
But is it possible to set Sorthandlers or the Celltable, so that they only sort in one way?
I only want to set the highest valueof the column on top, no matter wich column is clicked.
Everytime i need to click twice on a column so that the highest value is on top, because if the table is sorted from highest to lowest then it will be changed to lowest to highest.

i hope the description is not to complicated, so that somebody can help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, columns use ascending sort order (small values first). To change this, you can use

```java
myColumn.setDefaultSortAscending(false);
```